# "ValueError: invalid path in RECORD:" Gradle build error when installing Tensorflow using Chaquopy

Tags: python, android, gradle, chaquopy

I'm using Chaquopy to integrate a python script into an Android application in Android Studio. When installing tensorflow as a package, however, the build fails and this error pops up.

Gradle build fail message:

```
Collecting zipp>=0.5
  Using cached zipp-3.15.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.8 kB)
Installing collected packages: chaquopy-libgfortran, chaquopy-openblas, threadpoolctl, chaquopy-libcxx, numpy, scipy, joblib, scikit-learn, six, keras-preprocessing, termcolor, grpcio, absl-py, protobuf, wrapt, gast, setuptools, cachetools, pyasn1, rsa, pyasn1-modules, google-auth, oauthlib, charset-normalizer, urllib3, certifi, idna, requests, requests-oauthlib, google-auth-oauthlib, MarkupSafe, werkzeug, zipp, importlib-metadata, markdown, wheel, tensorboard, opt-einsum, tensorflow-estimator, astor, chaquopy-hdf5, h5py, keras-applications, google-pasta, tensorflow, pytz, python-dateutil, pandas, pyarabic, regex, click, tqdm, nltk
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-2.1.2 absl-py-1.4.0 astor-0.8.1 cachetools-4.2.4 certifi-2022.12.7 chaquopy-hdf5-1.10.2 chaquopy-libcxx-11000 chaquopy-libgfortran-4.9 chaquopy-openblas-0.2.20 charset-normalizer-3.1.0 click-8.1.3 gast-0.2.2 google-auth-1.35.0 google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.6 google-pasta-0.2.0 grpcio-1.39.0 h5py-2.10.0 idna-3.4 importlib-metadata-6.1.0 joblib-1.2.0 keras-applications-1.0.8 keras-preprocessing-1.1.2 markdown-3.4.1 nltk-3.8.1 numpy-1.19.5 oauthlib-3.2.2 opt-einsum-3.3.0 pandas-1.3.2 protobuf-4.22.1 pyarabic-0.6.15 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2022.7.1 regex-2021.10.23 requests-2.28.2 requests-oauthlib-1.3.1 rsa-4.9 scikit-learn-0.24.1 scipy-1.4.1 setuptools-67.6.0 six-1.16.0 tensorboard-2.1.1 tensorflow-2.1.0 tensorflow-estimator-2.1.0 termcolor-2.2.0 threadpoolctl-3.1.0 tqdm-4.65.0 urllib3-1.26.15 werkzeug-2.2.3 wheel-0.40.0 wrapt-1.15.0 zipp-3.15.0
WARNING: Target directory C:\Users\Omar\AndroidStudioProjects\graduation\app\build\pip\debug\arm64-v8a\tensorflow_core already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.
Target directory C:\Users\Omar\AndroidStudioProjects\graduation\app\build\pip\debug\arm64-v8a\tensorflow_core already exists. Specify --upgrade to force replacement.

Chaquopy: Failed to process C:\Users\Omar\AndroidStudioProjects\graduation\app\build\pip\debug\arm64-v8a\tensorflow-2.1.0.dist-info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\Omar\AndroidStudioProjects\graduation\app\build\generated\python\bp\chaquopy\pip_install.py", line 366, in <module>
    PipInstall().main()
  File "C:\Users\Omar\AndroidStudioProjects\graduation\app\build\generated\python\bp\chaquopy\pip_install.py", line 59, in main
    req_infos, abi_trees[abi] = self.pip_install(abi, self.reqs)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Omar\AndroidStudioProjects\graduation\app\build\generated\python\bp\chaquopy\pip_install.py", line 146, in pip_install
    raise ValueError("invalid path in RECORD: '{}'".format(path))
ValueError: invalid path in RECORD: '../../lib/python/tensorflow_core/include/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/allocator_retry.h'

> Task :app:generateDebugPythonRequirements FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugPythonRequirements'.
> Process 'command 'py'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugPythonRequirements'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:142)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:327)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:307)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:293)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:417)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:339)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: com.chaquo.python.BuildPythonFailedException: Process 'command 'py'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Top-level build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.chaquo.python' version '14.0.2' apply false
}
```

Module-level build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.chaquo.python'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.graduation'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.graduation"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }

        python {
            version "3.8"
            pip {
                install "scikit-learn"
                install "tensorflow"
                install "pandas"
                install "numpy"
                install "pyarabic"
                install "nltk"
            }
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                python.srcDir "src/main/python"
            }
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        mlModelBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.1.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

This error only shows up when installing Tensorflow. I tried excluding it and the app was built successfully.

Comment: Hi, I'm the creator of Chaquopy. I can't reproduce this problem, so this will require a bit more exploration. I've created [this entry](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/825) on our issue tracker: please respond to my questions there.